# TSQL Copy an existing database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am learning how to administrate MS Sql server 2012, come cross a question and its suggested solution for copying an existing database for different name.

Administer a windows azure sql database named Orders, you need to create a copy of this table and renamed as Order_Reporting

```
CREATE DATABASE Order_Reporting COPY OF Orders
```

I was wondering whether such useful query could also be used in standard ms sql server some how?

Comment: When you say you want to make a copy, do you want to copy the schema or the schema and the data?  These are two different techniques.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was wondering whether such useful query could also be used in standard ms sql server some how?

No, `CREATE DATABASE .. COPY OF ..` is ONLY applicable to  [Azure SQL Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx)

As a side note,

> Copying a database using the CREATE DATABASE statement is an asynchronous operation. Therefore, a connection to the SQL Database server is not needed for the full duration of the copy process.  You can monitor the copy process with the sys.dm_database_copies and sys.databases views. The **sys.dm_operations_status** view can be used as well as it returns the status of database operations including database copy.

In order to create a copy of current database in SQL Server, you have to backup the database and then restore it with a different name

e.g.

```
backup database OriginalDB
to disk = 'D:\backup\OriginalDB_full.bak'
with init, stats =10;

restore database new_db_name
from disk = 'D:\backup\OriginalDB_full.bak'
with stats =10, recovery,
move 'logical_Data_file' to 'D:\data\new_db_name.mdf',
move 'logical_log_file' to 'L:\log\new_db_name_log.ldf'
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with SQL Server 2014 SP2 you can use the DBCC CLONEDATABASE command to duplicate an empty database. Here is a good primer on it

[Clone a SQL Server Database Using DBCC CLONEDATABASE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4410/clone-a-sql-server-database-using-dbcc-clonedatabase/)

Comment: Please note that `CLONEDATABASE` only clones the schema, not data